# directive scope array has the same elements even though controller has different elements. why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive where

```
scope: {
   cards : "="
}
```

In my controller `$scope.cards` starts empty and then after an async call to my server, I push objects into it. It ends uplooking something like this:

```
$scope.cards = [{name:"hello",type:"world"}, 
          {name:'different name',type:'different type'}, ...etc etc ]
```

This is displayed with a simple `card in cards` and then somewhere in the page `{{card.name}}`

When I go to my page indeed I see all the different names.

My directive allows me to pick up and drag the element. In my directive, I expect `scope.cards[i].name` to be different for each element. I use `console.log(scope.cards[i].name)` to see if the names are different (where i is the index for each element).

For some reason however, `scope.cards` is the same for each element. Specifically it is the last entry in `scope.cards`.

What's going on? Why is the directive assuming that all the elements inthe array are the same?

Comment: please provide a plunker

Comment: @AnkitLadhania actually I think my issue is that the index i is not changing. How do I scope.apply in a directive?

Comment: in the link function use `scope.$apply(function(){ //Do stuff here  })`

Comment: @AnkitLadhania Thank you didn't realize $apply was available. that did the trick!

Comment: please upvote the comment so that it recognized and try to add a answer yourself

Answer (score 0):

I initially believed my issue was that I did not use `scope.$apply`.

However upon further investigation, the issue was that my index was a primitive data type binded through my controller.

The below link is good to learn about scopes but basically, primitive data types create local copies in the directive. Therefore when I tried changing the value of the primitive by +=1, it did not change the parent value. Thus my index was always 0.

To correct this i had to make my index a non-primitive data type.

In my controller, instead of `$scope.my_index = 0` it became `$scope.my_index = [0]` which is an array where the first value is 0. Now in my directive `scope.my_index[0] = scope.my_index[0] + 1` works.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes